# How to maintain static and dynamic cell into TablViewController using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In myscenario, I have created `static` cell with multiple `sections`. Now, I need to load `dynamic` cell bottom of the last static cell. Here, I am using `UITableviewController` with cell type `Static`. I tried below code but it is not working. I can able to see only static cells but dynamic cell not loading.

[image]

**TableviewController Delegates**

```
var Titles = ["Food","Travel","Lifestyle","Card","MyReserve","Game","Songs","Movies","Entertainment","Business","Education","Finance","Drink","Sports","Social","Shopping"]

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if(section == 0) {
            return " "
        } else if(section == 1) {
            return " "
        } else if(section == 2) {
            return " "
        } else {
            return " "
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if (section == 0) {
            return 2
        } else if(section == 1) {
            return 1
        } else if(section == 2) {
            return 3
        }
        return self.Titles.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if indexPath.section != 0 && indexPath.section != 1 && indexPath.section != 2 {
            let celltitle. = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dynamiccell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
            celltitle.textLabel?.text = self.Titles[indexPath.row]
            return celltitle.
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        } else if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2 {
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Comment: try changing the content of tableview from static cells to dynamic prototypes.

Comment: @ThePedestrian if I change it. all display sections gone.

Comment: is it set to static cells?. If you're displaying cells from code. It wouldn't matter.

Comment: @ThePedestrian I am changing. I will update you here once I am done. Thanks buddy!

Comment: Don't thank me yet. Glad to be of help if it works :)

Comment: @ThePedestrian I am having multiple static cell right, So I am using same identifier but it is showing error `multiple prototype table cells have the same identifier Swift`

Comment: give each static cell a different identifier. The code will build successfully. if the cells are exactly the same you can use the same identifier. However, on storyboard, just have a single instance of that cell.

Comment: Did you get rid of that issue?